# Is it possible to implement Fingerprint authentication in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am using React.js to build mobile application. But I don't know how to implement fingerprint authentication like iPhone or android in React.js. I found there are a few plugin for React-Native. But I need it for react.js.

Can anybody help me to give a good advice or guideline for ReactJs?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using webauthn . Webauthn gives the option to use the fingerprint .

Answer (score -4):

I haven't tried myself but perhaps use a js library like this?
https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

Comment: This library doesn't scan fingerprints. It generates an unique ID based on browser and devicei nformation.